# Почему я получаю эти две ошибки?

Tags: c, функции

Я описал прототип функции `checkNull`, структуру `Word` и прототип функции `initDictionary` в заголовочном файле

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef LZWLIB_H_
#define LZWLIB_H_

typedef struct Word
{
    unsigned int code; 
    char * value; 
} Word;

void * checkNull(void* ptr); 
Word * initDictionary(const char* inpurFileName, unsigned int* freeCode);

#endif /* LZWLIB_H_ */
```

Теперь, когда я пишу реализацию функции `initDictionary` в файле `.c`

```
Word* initDictionary(const char * inputFileName, unsigned int * freeCode)
{
    // Реализация функции
}

int main ()
{
    char * s = "toCompress.txt";

    int freeCode = 0;
    int * fptr = &freeCode;
    Word * dictionary = initDictionary(s, fptr);

    printf("%d\n", freeCode);

    return 0;
}
```

minGW Выдает мне две ошибки:

```
lzwlib2.c:52:7: error: conflicting types for 'initDictionary'
 Word* initDictionary(const char * inputFileName, unsigned int * freeCode
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from lzwlib2.c:19:0:
lzwlib.h:16:8: note: previous declaration of 'initDictionary' was here
 Word * initDictionary(const char* inpurFileName, int * freeCode);
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Что они означают и как их исправить? Я уже нагулил [похожий вопрос на англоязычном StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549631/getting-conflicting-types-for-function-in-c-why), но там участник форума **сначала** вызывал функцию, а потом ее реализовывал. Я же раньше по коду написал реализацию, а затем вызов. Типы возвращаемых значений в прототипе и реализации совпадают. Почему я получил эти ошибки?

Comment: у тебя в хедере тип второго параметра `unsigned`, а компилятор говорит, что `int`... очевидно, что кто-то их вас врёт и я думаю, что это не компилятор...  а может быть ты просто файл забыл сохранить файл...

Comment: + `s` должно быть `const char*`

Comment: @EOF https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal

Comment: @dIm0n _"String literals are not modifiable (and in fact may be placed in read-only memory such as .rodata). If a program attempts to modify the static array formed by a string literal, the behavior is undefined."_

Comment: @EOF я к тому, что в C не "должно быть" в отличие от C++

Comment: @dIm0n Согласен, но рекомедуется)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь, что заголовочный файл в .cpp-файл включен :)

Вижу несколько проблем -

```
char * s = "toCompress.txt";
```

справа никак не `char*`, литерал может быть приведен к `const char*`, но не к `char*`.

```
initDictionary(const char* inpurFileName,  
               unsigned int* freeCode)
```

Второй параметр у вас описан как `unsigned int*`, но передаете вы в него `int*`.

Кстати, из сообщения компилятора следует,, что в заголовочном файле эта функция описана как

```
Word * initDictionary(const char* inpurFileName, int * freeCode);
```

Проверьте - там и в самом деле `int*`?

Я бы начал с исправления этих ошибок...

Comment: C 6.4.5/6: "... For character string literals, the array elements have type `char` ..."